# Creating jar file directory across?

Tags: java, jar, import, runtime-error

At first I have to say, that I've just started learning java a short while ago, so I'm not familiar with the language at all. Due to this, I try to get things done without using an IDE, so I can understand how things work. However, it's not the language that drives me crazy, but the process of making a .jar file.

I have the directories E:\Java\MyLib\mylib.java, E:\Java\Test\PartA\parta.java and E:\Java\Test\PartB\partb.java, which contains my main. mylib.java is a package that gets imported by parta.java, parta.java gets imported by partb.java.

I created a .bat file consulting several tutorials as much as the official specification from oracle about how to use the jar.exe, I've created a valid manifest.txt, I told the programm where it could find the partb.class containing my main, everything gets compiled to its own .class file just fine what tells me that my code is correct, but trying to merge all the files together into one .jar file took me hours without a working result.

According to any instructions I was able to find I'm doing everything right, I tried many different spellings and options, but at the end, either the compiler does not even find the files in the subfolders, or the files are in the .jar, but the javab.class is not able to find them during runtime.

It's sickening. I think I'm missing something, doing something absolutely wrong, but I can't figure out what it is. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Try including your batch file. You might also consider having a look at ant as an alternative make process

Comment: Including the batch file does not change anything, the imported files are still missing.

Comment: No, include in your post so we see what you're doing. Assuming rye doing it right, but not getting the results you expect suggest you're doing something wrong

Comment: I use Maven exactly because I don't want to have to deal with this stuff. IMHO, its much more important you understand the relationships between the manifest, dependencies, and your code (which is sounds like you do), than it is to know how to manually package a java app to a jar, because professionals use build tools. Making a jar manually only ensures that you understand how to make it virtually impossible for another developer to reproduce your build process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an IDE, it makes life so much easier. But, if you insist on doing things the old fashion way, try turning off your antivirus. If that doesn't work, check to make sure your environment variables are set correctly. If all else fails, try reinstalling your JDK.

Comment: I'm going to use an IDE in the near future, but I'm curious about how to get things working "old school".

Comment: Been there, done that. I hate it when people don't give you answers, just tell you to not do it.